# How to get the value of scrollY while using overflow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, overflow, react-spring

I've got the following [React app](https://codesandbox.io/s/41ny3ooj9) where I'm using react-spring to animate between routes and animate different elements based on the current scroll position.

When I use `overflow: scroll` on the `Home` component I'm then unable to return anything from my `handleScroll` method (it just returns 0):

```
  handleScroll(e) {
    let windowScrollPosition = window.scrollY
    this.setState({ windowScrollPosition: windowScrollPosition }, () => console.log(this.state.windowScrollPosition, 'this.state.windowScrollPosition'))
  }
```

Is there a way around this?

I need to use `overflow: scroll` to solve [this issue](https://github.com/drcmda/react-spring/issues/217) unfortunately.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well that would make sense. If you have set an element to scroll that is 100% height then the window would never scroll the element would.

So you need to get the scroll position from the element with `elem.scrollTop`

You can create a ref to the element in React

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scrollContainer = React.createRef();
}

return (
    <div className="scroll-container" ref={this.scrollContainer}></div>
)
```

And then in your handle scroll method use:

```
handleScroll(e) {
    let windowScrollPosition = this.scrollContainer.current.scrollTop | window.scrollY;
    this.setState({ windowScrollPosition: windowScrollPosition }, () => console.log(this.state.windowScrollPosition, 'this.state.windowScrollPosition'))
  }
```